# Spring POST request: Response from the template

Tags: java, spring, templates, spring-boot, thymeleaf

The problem here is that I don't know how to say in which variable should be save the information from the template

Controller Method:

```
@PostMapping("/users/register")
public String register(UserCreateRequestModel viewModel, Model model){
    if (this.userService.register(viewModel.getUsername(), viewModel.getPassword())){
        return "redirect:/";
    }
    model.addAttribute("viewModel", viewModel);
    return "users/register";
}
```

Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Register here</h1>
<form th:object="${viewModel}" method="post">
    Username: <input th:field="*{username}" name="username" type="text"     /></br>
    Password: <input th:field="*{password}" type="password" /></br>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This code is working, but i cannot understand how to say that I want information from the input fields to be filled in UserCreateRequestModel. This code is too magical for me. I was searching for an annotation but couldnt find such.

Comment: Use @RequestBody UserCreateRequestModel viewModel

Comment: this is not working

Comment: Use spring form tag in your template and mention modelAttribute=viewModel

Comment: I found the solution. It's @ModelAttribute, but you mention it is the properties of the method in the controller

Comment: Yes . Plz refer https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_form_handling_example.htm

Answer (score 0):

The solution is usage of @ModelAttribute("viewModel"). It is getting all viewModel fields.

```
@PostMapping("/users/register")
public String register(@ModelAttribute("viewModel") UserCreateRequestModel viewModel, Model model){
    //System.out.println(viewModel.getUsername());
    //System.out.println(1111);
    if (this.userService.register(viewModel.getUsername(), viewModel.getPassword())){
        return "redirect:/";
    }
    model.addAttribute("viewModel", viewModel);
    return "users/register";
}
```